# Display OLE Object(pdf) in axAcroPdf

Tags: c#, ms-access, ole, axacropdf

Is there any way to get a pdf from an access database and display it directly into an axAcroPdf control without having to save the document on the disk?

If this isn't possible with Access, can you recommend some other db to use? My "mentor" suggested I'd use firebird but until this problem occurred, access did everything I needed it to do.

Thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a limitation of the database but rather [`axAcroPdf`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/acrobat_sdk/9.1/Acrobat9_1_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=Acrobat9_HTMLHelp&file=IAC_API_OLE_Objects.103.175.html) which is just a wrapper for Acrobat Reader which does not support loading pdfs from memory.

Comment: I see, I also thought this was the problem, but my "mentor" aka my teacher kept telling me it's possible. Oh well.. Anyway, do you know if there are any pdf viewers for c# that could display the file without having to load it from disk?

Comment: I've heard that XPdfViewer (http://www.glyphandcog.com/XpdfViewerCtrl.html) supports this functionality (http://www.glyphandcog.com/support/q0008.html) but I've never used it myself.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but it's a bit too pricey for me, I guess I will stick with what I have for now.

Answer (score 0):

Would it work to just save the PDF to a temp area and then delete it when the form closes? Not an ideal solution but it would get round some of the problems